# How to add the value of barcode scanner in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner

I have multiple textboxes in my WindowsForm. Whenever I scan with Barcode Scanner, I should click the textbox first, then scan. However, I want the barcode scanner's value to be placed on a specific textbox whenever I scan. Is there a specific code or option for that?

Comment: Barcode scanners are basically keyboards. What UI framework are you using? For winforms you can just do the `textBoxName.Focus()` to move input focus to a particular textbox.

Comment: You can set Focus method like txtscanbarcode.Focus();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the scanner working properly and it gives you the values to the selected textbox. By clicking on textbox control, you are giving the focus to that control. so do it programmatically while loading the form using `textBox1.Focus();` method; Let `Form1` be your form and `textBox1` be the respective textbox, the The code would be like the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all whenever you scan any barcode scanner will read that values and paste that value into an active textbox so if your requirement is scanning barcodes in only particular one textbox then you can set the focus of that barcode in form load event like below.

```
        private void DataLoging_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
         txtBarcode.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In My opinion Barcode scan is same as keyboard input it's just coming from barcode scanner. so if you want it to be placed in only one textbox you have multiple options

->if your barcode have pattern write method to detect that pattern and check in all textbox's textchange event if that's barcode if so fill your required textBox

```
public static void CheckForbarcode(TextBox origin)
{
string data=origin.Text;
// asssuming your barcode is 12 digit long

    if(data.Length==12)
    {
     //Regex Pattern goes here
     origin.Text="";
     Barcode.text=data;
    }

}
```

Second set focus to that textbox after any operation is completed

Answer (score 0):

#### The barcode scanner

The barcode scanner is a keyboard (just doesn't look like one).

---

#### Focus TextBox

The TextBox can be focused using

```
tbxBarcode.Focus();
```

---

#### Focus TextBox Automatically

If the textBox isn't focused and you scan something, it won't be written.

Use the form's event `KeyDown` to check if something is being scanned but without writing in `tbxBarcode`.

---

#### Multiple barcodes

You can use the `tbxBarcode.TextChanged` event to know if the barcode was fully scanned and programmatically press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If the barcode presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> after scanning is even better, because you can use that in `textBox1.KeyDown` and getting `e.KeyValue == Keys.Enter` to run `btnNextBarcode.PerformClick()`